# Jquery ajax simple form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm sending form data to a PHP file via AJAX, using jquery I hoped I could send the data easily seeing as it's only one text box etc. On submit click event the form data should be serialised and sent to submit.php, then I should get an alert from the php file with the response. Why doesn't it work?
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 


$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'submit.php', data:$('#myform').serialize(), success:
function(response) {
alert(response);
}});

});

</script>
```

Then the HTML:

```
<form id="myform" >
<input type="text" name="content" value="button should be on same line" /><input 
type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"  id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I would recommend you handle this in the form submit event handler and not the submit button click event because if you press enter inside the form it will trigger the form submit.. therefore triggering the default form submit instead of the ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initalized the DOM ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   // do your work here
});
```

EDIT :

Try this:

```
    $("#submit").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 


          $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'submit.php', data:$('#myform').serialize(), success:
            function(response) {
              alert(response);
             }});
           });


 });
```

Comment: Worked a treat, you saved me so much time thanks. I'm rushing things, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to determine that the form is submitting correctly. try submitting to

```
 url: '/submit.php'
```

instead, as that may not have been the correct path.

Second, try sending the value unserialized and see if you get a correct.